# What’s the terminal code to enable locking mac using the touch ID key on Ventura?

Tags: catalina, touch-id, lockscreen

I’m on ventura (MBA 2019) and I remember using terminal to disable this feature due to some reason. Anyone knows how to reverse it?

Much appreciated.

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate, please reopen the post. (This comment is addressing people with the ability to reopen posts or at least vote for it)

Comment: @Thinkr What makes you think that it isn't a duplicate?

Comment: @nohillside Because when I answered there, I did not felt like I was answering the same problem.

Comment: @thinkr We close as dupes if the answers to the new question are the same as to another one.

Comment: @nohillside My answer was present in none of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo bioutil --write --system --unlock 1
```

Comment: @DaveNN this does not seem to be working for me. Tried turning off and on again as well. Any other suggestion?